# Need to build a lip on half the front of the shower pan

Tags: shower, waterproofing, plumbing-fixture, tiling

I have a bit of a situation...

I have a 3x5 Fiberglass reinforced acrylic construction designed for a 3 wall alcove.  However, in my infinite wisdom, I overlooked this crucial detail and proceeded to mortar the thing in place prior to building the 2' wall in front in which I installed my vanity (and of course drywalled/finished).  At the time of construction, I was in a bind and thought I would engineer flashing to divert the possibility of water getting over the curb on the front portion that is against the wall.  The other 3' or so of the front is just where you would enter/exit the shower. A door or curtain will protect this.

I went ahead and started to DenShield the back wall to get an idea of how everything works on that bottom profile.  The lip from the factory is substantial.  It's a good 3/4" tall and it's also a good 3/16" thick, meaning it protrudes the bottom edge of my tile board.  Per manufacture install instructions, I am to cover 1/2" of that lip, and leave 1/4" gap between board and the bevel of the pan for obvious reasons such as water wickiing into the tile board over time.

Right now I am at a loss of a permanent solution for the front lip creation.  I originally was thinking some kind of plastic or pvc molding epoxied to the pan with something like those big box store 2 part mixes in a squeeze tube.  I fear this would fail over years of use?  Either the plastic would break or the bond would break if that portion of the shower was ever bumped into from all the weight.  A tiler told me to just silicon the gap between tile board and pan, leaving my entire protection on a bead of silicon that is supposed to adhere to a painted acrylic pan and a fiberglass/gypsum type tile board.  This seems sketchy, too.

Anyone have a better idea?  A type of adhesive that would work for molding/welding/melting the lip to the pan for this 2' section?

Edit: Added picture.  See the front? No lip, just a rounded nice edge for entering.  Sides and back have that lip pictured.
[image: One side of pan that has lip vs the front]

Comment: A picture would be so helpful here.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it I added a pic to original post.

Comment: It is not meant to have anything on the front. The lip on the sides and the back actually sit behind the tile. You but the hardy backer or the dens shield  to the lip and then when you tile the tile goes down beyond the lip and sits in front of it with just a bead of caulk between the surround and the tile

Comment: That would make sense, because otherwise my tile mastic would need to feather out so that the bottom 12" of the board does not bow in.  However, for the portion that I *do* need to tile and waterproof, I am trying to figure out what material and products to use to create a similar lip that serves the same purpose for 30" of the front bevel.  Was almost thinking about rolling out water weld into a snake and molding it to the edge of the lip.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it I am thinking about rolling out snakes of JB Water Weld to form a lip on the edge of the shower base.  The dens-shield would butt to this, then tile would face all of this with silicon below it.